# ArcgisMap to write a default lat/log location

Tags: java, android, arcgis, esri

Hi,

I'm a newbie in developing ArcGIS maps. Currently, I am able to display the map. But how can I create a default location using the longitude and latitude and implement this in my code?

For example, I want to set these coordinates: (1.3002, 103.8641). When you open the map, it will automatically zoom in to those coordinates.

Thank you in advance.

This is my code:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity {
MapView mMapView = null;
ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer tileLayer;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Retrieve the map and initial extent from XML layout
    mMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);
    /* create a @ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer */
    tileLayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(
            "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");
    // Add tiled layer to MapView
    mMapView.addLayer(tileLayer);

}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.pause();
    }

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume(); 
    mMapView.unpause();
}   

  }
```

Comment: I tried implementing the codes you have me , but when I write it in my codes . It asked me to create a class.and I got error on the geometry engine line and mMapview.centerat.

Comment: `import com.esri.core.geometry.GeometryEngine;`

Or Ctrl+Shift+O to make Eclipse fix your imports for you.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding any layers to the [`MapView`](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/MapView.html), set its [`OnStatusChangedListener`](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/event/OnStatusChangedListener.html). Add code to the listener that [projects the longitude/latitude coordinates to map coordinates](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/core/geometry/GeometryEngine.html#project%28double,%20double,%20com.esri.core.geometry.SpatialReference%29) and [centers the map](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/MapView.html#centerAt%28com.esri.core.geometry.Point,%20boolean%29) at the map coordinates.

You could do it like this:

```
mMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);

final double longitude = 103.8641;
final double latitude = 1.3002;
mMapView.setOnStatusChangedListener(new OnStatusChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(Object source, STATUS status) {
        if (STATUS.INITIALIZED.equals(status)) {
            Point mapPoint = GeometryEngine.project(longitude, latitude, mMapView.getSpatialReference());
            mMapView.centerAt(mapPoint, false);
        }
    }

});

/* create a @ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer */
tileLayer = new ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer(
        "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer");
// Add tiled layer to MapView
mMapView.addLayer(tileLayer);
```

If you want to both center and zoom to a certain scale, you can call [`zoomToScale`](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/android/api-reference/reference/com/esri/android/map/MapView.html#zoomToScale%28com.esri.core.geometry.Point,%20double%29) instead of `centerAt`.